# How can I perfect my backyard ice rink?

Tags: winter, ice, iceskating

I live in the northeast US and have a depression in my backyard: after weeks of freezing weather we had a warm, rainy weekend. Then it all froze =)

So now I have a backyard rink, about 100' x 50' (30m x 15m), but I'd like to get it flatter and better-suited to skating. There are spots where it was slushy and a bootprint froze in, ridges and ripples from who-knows-what, &c.

I'm willing to build apparatus to help me, but would rather not spend much. (Say, under $100 US.) I'm willing to spend up to an hour a day out there working to maintain the rink.

I'm **not willing** to just flood it to a depth of two inches to set a new layer: that'd take *way* too much water.<sup>*</sup> I want to use the existing ice (and surrounding snow, if more water's needed) as much as possible.

**How can I perfect this rink and ensure my kids the best skating every afternoon, all winter?**

---

<sup>* - I know because two years ago, last time this happened, I tried just flooding it. There's enough topography to the ice that In a month of late-night floodings I wasn't able to raise the level enough to effect changes to imperfections on the not-level portions.</sup>

Comment: I'm far from an expert but I'm sure you'll have to add *some* liquid water. Would you be happy with an answer that set out to minimise this?

Comment: Do you happen to have anything like a 4-wheeler or riding lawnmower that could be improvised into a Zamboni?

Comment: @ChrisH absolutely. I just won't use anything like 100'x50'x3" of water =) (See new footnote for some more context.)

Comment: @CharlieBrumbaugh I might be able to borrow one... if you've got an answer that uses one and gets massively-upvoted, that'll put the pressure on me to do my neighbor a favor or two =)

Comment: What are conditions like during the day? Presumably below freezing but does the sun soften the surface? I'm wondering about adding snow to the low patches in the morning, and watering it as soon as the sun goes off it.

Comment: @ChrisH it does get full sun, such as that is on the solstice at 42N =) I'll go out midday to take a feel--any advice on how I should "measure"/characterize its softness?

Comment: We don't even see snow every year here so I'm hardly an expert.  I'm thinking in terms of wetness, or whether it could be relied upon to flow over the surface (when  wetted), then freeze hard overnight

Comment: That would be a lot of water: 1,250 cu ft. = ~ 9350 gallons

Comment: @ChrisH the sun will not melt snow to the extent that any perceptible water would flow over the ice and re-freeze. It's almost-sufficient--as long as it's not cloudy--to deal with the tiny bits of snow that are left behind when I shovel twice.

Comment: Elsewhere on SE: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/3961/how-do-i-build-an-ice-rink-in-my-backyard/7971#7971 and http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/2704/what-sort-of-hose-nozzle-should-i-look-for-such-that-it-wont-spring-a-leak-afte/2705#2705

Comment: @KateGregory the DIY link is amazing and excellent and wonderful. I hope you'll consider cross-posting it here.

Comment: I don't think we're supposed to (mod opinion?). I'm glad you found it helpful. Enjoy your rink, and the peaceful time maintaining it on calm cold nights.

Answer (score 9):

We have a pond on our farm and often groom the ice for ice skating. We have a pretty simple 3-step process that takes about 20 minutes with a couple of people and gives us great ice:

1. Shovel off any snow. The melting/freezing snow really ruins your
   ice. We use a metal bladed shovel which also helps to knock off any
   bumps in the ice. (Some loose ice shavings help with the next step, anyways.)
2. Spray/dump warm water over the ice. In your case where you don't want to have to add water the weed burner will probably work. You just need a thin layer of water to work with.
3. Level the water as needed. We just use a large push broom to ensure we get even coverage. Ultimately, gravity is your friend here and the water should settle to be completely smooth before it freezes, the broom is only used to help push water around. If your hose reaches all areas, then you likely won't even need the broom.

A few notes:

- Don't try to do this if it is windy. It will still work, but not as well.
- Keeping snow off of the ice is the most important part.
- As others have mentioned, keep people off the ice while it is setting.
- Work with your temperature. If it is going to be above freezing for a little while, just let the sun do all the work for you and let it re-freeze over night. If it is very cold (we get down around -10F at times) you'll need more/warmer water as it freezes so fast.

For reference take a look at step three of Bob Vila's [3 Simple Steps to a Backyard Ice Skating Rink](https://www.bobvila.com/articles/backyard-ice-rink/#.WFxQlhsrJhE). (Yes, it really is just as easy as it sounds).

Comment: IMHO a Zamboni would be some pretty gross overkill.

There are two different circumstances we have to groom the ice. The first is at the end of the day/prepping for the next day. We use a hose, and just shoot water out over all the ice. Let it sit and the next morning you're good to go!
The second scenario is after the ice has been roughed up from use -- for that we use a much smaller amount of water  (so it freezes faster) and the push broom. You're essentially just painting the ice. Let it sit for 5-10 minutes and you're good to go! (You may not even need/want the broom).

Answer (score 6):

Obvious try and keep people off the ice when it is soft.

[Ice resurfacer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_resurfacer)

> Before Zamboni 3 or 4 workers had to scrape, wash, and squeegee the
>   ice. A thin layer of water was then added for the fresh ice. This
>   process was extremely time consuming, and Zamboni wanted to find a
>   more efficient way to resurface the ice.
>
> Hot water is frequently used because it slightly melts the layer of
>   ice below it, forming a stronger bond when frozen, and because heating
>   the water drives off dissolved gases. This limits chipping and
>   cracking, providing a more enjoyable skating surface.

It is not clear how they scraped but I would try a tool like is used for scraping tile off a floor.  Then sweep the chips off.  Then add a small amount of hot water to the problem spots.  For a squeegee I would look at a roller squeegee like is used for tennis courts.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're suggesting, here. Surely a Zamboni can't be bought for anything even close to $100. So are you recommending the pre-Zamboni techniques mentioned in the quote?

Answer (score 6):

It looks like to build a homemade Zamboni, you need some type of powered transport like a [four-wheeler](http://globalnews.ca/news/2430351/alberta-engineers-design-homemade-zamboni-for-outdoor-rink/), [riding lawnmower](http://hackaday.com/2012/12/06/backyard-zamboni-keeps-the-best-diy-ice-rink-in-town/) or a [kid on a tricycle](http://www.neatorama.com/2016/02/29/Homemade-Zamboni-2/). Then you need a supply of hot water and something to spread it out behind the vehicle. The plans that I have seen usually have a water tank that has a hose going down to a PVC pipe with holes in it and a towel behind.

There are more detailed instructions [here](http://www.schoolyardpuck.com/2012/01/backyard-rink-diy-homzamboni.html) and another story with explanation [here](http://bangordailynews.com/2016/02/04/news/aroostook/homemade-zamboni-helps-rink-stay-smooth/).

YouTube has all kinds of [videos](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=vid&q=home%20made%20zamboni&rct=j) on this.

Answer (score 6):

I don't ice skate and my main goals of working with ice are to get it gone.  That said, if I did want to even out ice with the least amount of work and expense I would get a weed burner and a bottle of propane.

Inexpensive weed burns can be purchased for [about $20 US](http://www.harborfreight.com/propane-torch-91033.html)  it easily connects to the 5 gallon propane grill bottle, if you don't have a propane grill, some you know probably does, borrow it and refill it before returning.  Don't use disposable propane bottles, that would be expensive.

Use the weed burner to melt the high spots, they should melt and level out with the rest of the ice. If you want to get fancy for another [$10](http://www.webstaurantstore.com/24-black-floor-cleaning-squeegee/27140076.html?utm_source=Google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=GoogleShopping&gclid=Cj0KEQiAkO7CBRDeqJ_ahuiPrtEBEiQAbYupJWUhLftPbCSr7O40UX0su2mzGGuQdZZtqkH7OobAGmIaAvyF8P8HAQ) you can get a push Squeegee and get a nice smooth finish on the whole area.

[image: weed burner image]

Comment: Commercial links are for example only, there are lots of examples, do your own shopping, i just picked these randomly.

Comment: I like this idea :) Weed burners are lots of fun.

Comment: Before the first energy crisis in the early 1970s, a firm called Combustion Engineering was working on a humonguous mobile snow clearer for cities.  The snow would be scooped into the enclosed part, melted and then put down the storm drains.

Comment: @ab2 Here is an xkcd what if where the idea of using a flamethrower to clear snow was explored https://what-if.xkcd.com/130/

Comment: This is a brilliant suggestion.  God help us all if you decide to use your genius in pursuit of world domination.

Comment: @Charlie Brumbaugh I checked the numbers in your link; they are OK.  However the picture is misleading.  You don't need three aircraft carriers; all you need is a ["semi" truck gasoline tanker](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=gasoline+tanker+truck) attached to your car, with another semi ready to refuel the first every 25 miles.  (I wish someone would check my numbers, because intuitively this doesn't seem like enough.)